# Why did Polymer remove the hosted script and link from their site?

Tags: html, web, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

Recently I came to add some Paper-Elements to my web and I did not find hosted script and link for their Elements. I'm really lazy to upload all js and css files to my web. So is there any reason for Polymer to remove the hosted links in their latest version? Or did  they not remove it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a support question.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why they removed or did anything to it, but you can use http://polygit.org/.

```
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/master/webcomponents.js"></script>
     <base href="http://polygit.org/polymer:+v1.1.0/components/">
     <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
...
```

and for production deploy I'd suggest vulcanizing it: https://github.com/polymer/vulcanize .